# iOS crasher: CFNetwork HTTPReadFilter::doPlainRead(StreamReader*, unsigned char*, long, CFStreamError*, unsigned char*)

Tags: ios, ios8

I have this crasher which happens a lot in our production app but we are not able to reproduce it. It happened only on iOS8 using iOS8 SDK.

```
HTTPReadFilter::doPlainRead(StreamReader*, unsigned char*, long, CFStreamError*, unsigned char*) inside CFNetwork. Crashed: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000

StackTrace:

        libsystem_platform.dylib    
    _platform_memmove + 185

    CFNetwork   
    HTTPReadFilter::doPlainRead(StreamReader*, unsigned char*, long, CFStreamError*, unsigned char*) + 178

    CFNetwork   
    HTTPReadFilter::_streamImpl_Read(unsigned char*, long, CFStreamError*, unsigned char*) + 394

    CFNetwork   
    CoreStreamBase::_streamInterface_Read(unsigned char*, long) + 98

    CFNetwork   
    HTTPNetStreamInfo::_streamImpl_Read(__CFReadStream*, unsigned char*, long, CFStreamError*, unsigned char*) + 306

    CFNetwork   
    CFNetworkReadStream::httpStreamRead(__CFReadStream*, unsigned char*, long, CFStreamError*, unsigned char*, void*) + 44

    CoreFoundation  
    CFReadStreamRead + 328

    CFNetwork   
    HTTPNetStreamInfo::_readStreamClientCallBack(__CFReadStream*, unsigned long) + 128

    CFNetwork   
    CFNetworkReadStream::_readStreamClientCallBackCallBack(__CFReadStream*, unsigned long, void*) + 38

    CoreFoundation  
    _signalEventSync + 146

    CoreFoundation  
    _cfstream_shared_signalEventSync + 342
        CoreFoundation  
    __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 14
        CoreFoundation  
    CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106

    CFNetwork   
    +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 486
        Foundation  
    __NSThread__main__ + 1118
        libsystem_pthread.dylib 
    _pthread_start + 118
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Seeing this as well. Are you seeing this on all arch or only arm64?

Comment: Can you give us more context, are you using `SDWebImage` by chance?

Comment: Not using SDWebImage, but I am making webservice calls to update my product images. `[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&resp error:&err];` is my line which I run in a blockOperation which is inside a for-loop. It is happening only on iOS-8 and happens like every few minutes. Somewhere somehow `req` object is giving EXC_BAD_ACC.  @RyanRomanchuk were you able to trace down your problem?

Comment: Any chance you are using google analytics?

Comment: @RyanRomanchuk Yes we are using Google Analytics v3.03C.

Comment: GA is the only common thread i can find between another user that also has this crash.

Comment: I have the same crash and am not using Google Analytics

Comment: I had contacted Apple and they had asked me to file a bug report. I saw that they have marked this issue as duplicate, that means there are others out there who saw this problem and Apple might fix it in some new release. I am going to give them this stack overflow link, so that they know this is an important issue and they might change the priority.

Comment: same issue here, also using Google Analytics, although that just might be a Red Herring since it's really common and you often have another thread running some GAI code.

Comment: @Bersaelor what version of Google Analytics are you guys using? I had 3.03C and am going to update it to the latest 3.10

Comment: @PrasadAvhad I solved my crash yesterday, it was caused by a network-request going into an infinite loop. It really had nothing to do with GAI. It is just that in any of our Crashreports one of the many open threads will show  as the Google-Analytics Thread.

Comment: try this https://charangiri.wordpress.com/2014/09/25/crash-report-ios/

instead of showing alert give some option as "mail to owner of app" or write a web service where you can get this information automatically to your mail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be really an iOS 8 bug. Try to not set a custom size for your NSURLCache. Check this https://devforums.apple.com/message/1102182#1102182

Comment: Thank you for this link Raphael. I am not customizing size of NSURLCache. I am just doing this [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses]; when app launches and then in one webservice call I am doing this     [request setCachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:request];  Do you know if this will also affect this CFNetwork crash? I am doing this because sometimes app won't clear off cache and not look at server response.

Comment: I don't know if the code you mention is also causing the crash. I'm yet to update my version on the AppStore removing the custom size for NSURLCache. I'll post here the result.

Comment: Just to state, not setting a custom size for the NSURLCache indeed solved the problem. It's a workaround for a bug from Apple.

Comment: Thanks Raphael. I am going to try and avoid using [NSURLCache removeAllCachedResponses] and see if it helps us in any way.

Comment: We used a different library to download images and that got rid of CFNetwork crasher. Thank you Raphael.